# Find the matrix $P$ that multiplies $(x, y, z)$ to give $(y, z, x)$. Find the matrix $Q$ that multiplies $(y, z, x)$ to bring back $(x, y, z)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve these types of problems? What method or technique do I use? I want to learn how to solve the first one so that I can try to figure out the second part to the question myself.

Comment: Do you know what are permutation matrices?

Comment: no, but I will look it up, the more I know the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naive Method:** (i.e. without knowing what permutation matrices are) $$\big(x,y,z\big)\cdot\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i}=\big(ax+dy+gz,bx+ey+hz,cx+fy+iz\big),$$ you're looking for reals $a,b,c,d,e,f,$ and $i$ such that, $$\big(ax+\color{green}{dy}+gz,bx+ey+\color{#C00}{hz},\color{royalblue}{cx}+fy+iz\big)=\big(\color{green}y,\color{#C00}z,\color{royalblue}x\big).$$ **NB:** It would be interesting if you could notice the pattern, and make a generalization for such cases.

Comment: So the answer is $$\big(x,y,z\big)\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}$$, this would give me $$\big(y, z, x\big)$$

Comment: and for the second part I would multiply these $$\big(y,z,x\big)\cdot\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}$$ this would give me $$\big(x,y,z\big)$$

Comment: @idknuttin Correct!

Answer (score 1):

The first row of $P$ is the image of $(1,0,0)$, the second row of $P$ is the image of $(0,1,0)$ and the third row of $P$ is the image of $(0,0,1)$. Therefore
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This exploits the fact that the $i$-th row of $P$ is $e_1P$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th basic vector (the $i$-th row of the identity), which must be the image of this vector under the given map.

Similarly, you can compute the images of the basic vectors under $Q$ or simply compute the inverse of $P$:
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
&& R_1\leftrightarrow R_2 \\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
&& R_2\leftrightarrow R_3
\end{align}
so
$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This method of computing the inverse uses Gaussian elimination on the matrix $(P\mid I)$, whose reduced row echelon form is the matrix $(I\mid P^{-1})$

Note that $Q$ is actually the transpose of $P$, which always happens with permutations matrices.

Comment: If I multiply (x,y,z) by your P I would get (z, x, y), the problem asks for (y, z, x)

Comment: @idknuttin As you see, I used column vectors, rather than row vectors. I'll change it.